# where are BlenderKit materials stored

Tags: materials, add-on

I downloaded Blenderkit, and I can see in the shading nodes the materials I have applied to my object. But are the materials stored somewhere on my PC? Where can I find them

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the addons settings (menu Edit > Preferences > Addons > Blenderkit) you have lots of options including where the libraries will be downloaded:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that!